# UE4 Blueprints - how to make sure an actor wont be created within another actor

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So i have an unreal blueprint for a spawnarea collision box, that, spawns actors in it. In the main spawn blueprint(which is just in the event graph) and am spawning actors the `Add Child Actor Component` in the blueprint, and i want to make sure that the actor i am spawning won't be touching or within the bounds of an already spawned actor and nothing i've tried yet works. Here's my code:
[i can't embed images yet so here you go!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5QwT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a unique need for actor components for some reason, it would be more intuitive to spawn actors using the Spawn Actor from Class node. This node has an option to adjust position when spawning so it does not overlap other actors (collision handling override: Adjust position but always spawn)

If that's not good enough then you will have to write your own distribution logic. The easiest would be to simply create new random positions until you find one that is not within a specific distance of an existing actor.

Comment: Adjust position but always spawn - simple spawning objects one in another, no matter what collision